# Should I charge VAT on a customer who is VAT registered in a EU country?

Tags: united-kingdom, vat

I hope the title explains it all. I supply goods which are taxable in UK.
If the EU customer is not taxable, should I zero rate it or is the transaction outside the scope of VAT ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your customer is VAT-registered in their home country, provides their full VAT number, and you do some paperwork, then it's zero-rated for VAT. If your customer is not VAT-registered, then you need to charge VAT the same as if they were in the UK. See [here](http://www.hmrc.gov.uk/vat/managing/international/exports/goods.htm#1) for full details.

However, if you're selling more than a threshold amount to another EU country (generally a few tens of thousands of Euro, but it varies by country), then you have to register for VAT in that country.